# Turn dairy ceramic pot into parve pot

Tags: halacha, cooking-bishul, meat-and-milk

Can a ceramic pot which I used for cooking milk, very rarely and a long time ago, be turned into a parve pot to boil water only?

The pot is actually granitware, constructed of low-carbon steel with glass coating. I would like to use it to boil water for tea, mostly. May I use this water to add to chicken soup?

Comment: What are you going to do with this water?

Comment: Ariane, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing your question here! Please note that the site makes no guarantee of validity, and does not offer professional (particularly rabbinic) advice: treat information from this site like it came from a crowd of your friends. Might I recommend you [register](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account? That will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: The pot is actually granitware, constructed of low carbon steel with glass coating.  I would like to use it to boil water for tea, mostly.  May I use this water to add to chicken soup ?  Thank you, Ariane

Answer (score 1):

The general rule is that ceramic dishes cannot be koshered. If they are thickly glazed they may be koshered through not using them for at least 12 months. Unglazed ones cannot be koshered at all. The same should apply when changing the kosher typology (basari to parve, for example). [Kashering dishes - Chinaware](http://www.myjewishlearning.com/practices/Ritual/Kashrut_Dietary_Laws/Keeping_Kosher/Kashering_Making_Kosher_/Dishes.shtml)

Comment: But when changing "typology" there are issues of nat bar nat which could lead to extra leniencies, particularly when it has been 12 months.

Comment: There are also rabbinical decrees in changing the "typology" of utensils which go beyond normal "non-kosher to kosher." The poskim were worried that if you constantly changed the "typology" of your dishes, it would lead to mix-ups, and they therefore discouraged or perhaps prohibited it unless it was a great need.

Comment: From the Torah, everything is parve 24 hours after it's been cleaned...  And his has a glass coating, which according to some minhagim means it can be used interchangeably for meat or milk just like any other glass dish.

Answer (score 0):

Ceramic is not generally treated as "kasher-able". However, "low-carbon steel with glass coating" does not sound like ceramic and generally speaking, both metal and glass can be kashered. There is an Ashkenazi custom not to change the "genders" of kosher pots (e.g. between milchig and fleishig) even when kashering is an option (e.g. if the pot had become treif).  However, one loophole I've heard of is kashering for Pesach which is still traditionally allowed and would leave the option of "gender-change" open.  Though halacha l'maaseh queries are supposed to be left to your rabbi (who might have an issue with the use of a ha'arama - deceptive loophole manipulation).

Comment: Actually, there is probably a solid argument to be made that glass surfaces don't acquire a meat/dairy status at all because they are not terribly absorptive. And I believe Rav Herschel Schachter of YU has been qutoed as exploring if modern stainless steel might have a similar status.)

Comment: Ashkenazim don't kasher glass